# ssh2 connection to sftp server not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ssh2

I'm trying to connect to a sftp server with ssh2_php extension in a lavarel proyect.
The connection work great in a simple php script but the same code doesn't working when i take it to a controller in a blank laravel project.

This is the code of the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    public function test() {

        try {
            $ssh          = ssh2_connect(SFTP_SERVER, 22);
            $login        = ssh2_auth_password($ssh, SFTP_USER, SFTP_PASS);
            $sftp         = ssh2_sftp($ssh);
            $sftp_fd      = intval($sftp);
            $filesystem   = opendir("ssh2.sftp://$sftp_fd/.");
        } catch (\Throwable $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

     }
}
```

And here is the error response in postman:

[image]

As you can see the catch is not catching the error for some reason.

I'm working with php version 7.2

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ssh2_*` functions will not throw an exception on failure. Read up on the documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php (also check out the other functions you are using)

If you want to throw an exception when connection fails, I would do something like this:

```
$ssh = ssh2_connect(SFTP_SERVER, 22);
if (!$ssh) throw Exception("ssh2_connect failed");
# Do the same for the other functions, check their documentation for return values that designate failure
```

It might also be the case that everything is working as expected, in which case you aren't sending a response at all, which might explain the `ECONNRESET`.